# How to use apns-collapse-id with FCM?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I know this question have been asked many times but none of the answers work for me. Some of the questions dont even have an answer.

I am try to bundle or group similar notifications on ios. I am using FCM Cloud Functions to trigger notifications.

Following are the methods i tried by

```
const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: "Your medical history is updated" + Math.random(),
          tag: "MedicalHistory",
        },
        data: {
          click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
          sound: "default",
          status: "done",
        },
      };

      const patchedPayload = Object.assign({}, payload, {
        apns: {
          headers: {
            "apns-collapse-id": "MedicalHistory",
          },
        },
      });

      const options = {
        priority: "high",
        collapseKey: "MedicalHistory",
      };


await admin
          .messaging()
          .sendToDevice("MY_TOKEN", patchedPayload, options);
```

The above code does not work

```
const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: "Your medical history is updated" + Math.random(),
          tag: "MedicalHistory",
        },
        data: {
          click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
          sound: "default",
          status: "done",
        },
        apns: {
          headers: {
            "apns-collapse-id": "MedicalHistory",
          },
        },
      };



const options = {
            priority: "high",
            collapseKey: "MedicalHistory",
          };

 await admin
              .messaging()
              .sendToDevice("MY_TOKEN", payload, options);
```

This does not work as well.

I dont understand where to put the `apns-collapse-id`. The cloud functions sample also does not show this. Neither i could find doc with code on this

Comment: Can you just try changing your options parameter collapseKey with collapse_key? I looked at your 2nd payload looks like you have put `apns-collapse-id. ` at the correct place.

Comment: perhaps sendToDevice function gives a promise so put .then and .catch and try to look for the errors. imclude the logs in your question

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using the latest `send` function from the `firebase-admin` lib, usage described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#customize-messages-across-platforms).

It seems to work fine and somewhat easier to apply.

An example of a message with android/ios specific headers:

```js
// common data for both platforms
const notification = {
 title: 'You liked!',
 body: 'You really liked something...',
}
const fcmToken = '...'

// android specific headers
const android = {
  collapseKey: '0'
}

// ios specific headers
const apns = {
  headers: {
    "apns-collapse-id": '0'
  }
}

// final message
const message = {
 token: fcmToken,
 notification: notification,
 android: android,
 apns: apns,
}

// send message
admin.messaging().send(message).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: for android, collapseKey is now collapse_key. so it will be collapse_key:'YOUR_KEY'